# ROS and ADC/DAC Hardware

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Three questions on ROS-hardware interface--

Has anyone used ROS with National Instruments DAQ Cards such as the PCI-6225?  It appears to be possible to run it under linux using the [Comedi drivers](https://groups.google.com/group/comedi_list/browse_thread/thread/f886fdaebb57adce?pli=1), but I don't have a good feel for how much work this would require.

In the same vein, does anyone have recommendations for library and/or hardware choices for motor controllers under ROS?  There appear to be [stacks for the EPOS/ELMO controlllers](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/motor-control-driver-CiA-DSP-402-EPOS-ELMO-td1997926.html#a2010998), but I'd be curious to hear any feedback on how hard they are to set up, and on any other options.

Finally, what sort of latency could one expect from passing messages between ROS nodes on a fairly good machine running data acquisition (say a couple dozen analog inputs) and a few standard processing pipelines?  One user mentions [seeing up to 9ms](http://answers.ros.org/question/1015/publisher-subscriber-teleoperation-high-latency) for a basic packet reflector, but also seems to think this is unexpectedly high.  Is it reasonable to tweak ROS to give <1ms consistently for at least one or two important control loops?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10187/ros-and-adc/dac-hardware/) by [ljentoft](https://answers.ros.org/users/657/ljentoft/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We use NI cards with Orocos so you could have a look how this is done.
In Leuven we also provide a [Ethercat library](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/soem.git), which is a wrapper around the Simple Open Ethercat Master. Already a number of robots successfully use this for their motor drivers and also to have high speed sensor acquisition. This can be done in combination with ROS (as for example on the AMIGO robot).
If you want to have low latency and real-time behaviour for your low level control, have a look at the [orocos rtt toolchain](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/orocos_toolchain_ros.git). You can use this seamlessly with ROS and have low level real-time behaviour.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0